# Mapping (reshaping) a static Eigen Matrix

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

I've got a 2 x 4 matrix that I want to represent as a 1 x 8 vector, put the result from `colPivHouseholderQr().solve` in it, and then return that 2 x 4 matrix.
I've read [this](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReshapeSlicing.html) and tried the following:

```
Matrix<float, 2, 4> X;
Eigen::Map<Matrix<float, 1, 8>> X_vec(X.data(), 2, 4); // Run-time error
X_vec = A.colPivHouseholderQr().solve(b);
return X;
```

However I get an error at run time:

> Assertion failed: v == T(Value), file eigen\eigen\src/Core/util/XprHelper.h, line 110

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The second and third argument of the `Eigen::Map` constructor are respectively the number of rows and columns of the *new* matrix. For fixed sized matrices, they should be the same as those provided as template arguments. So, you should write:

```
Eigen::Map<Matrix<float, 1, 8>> X_vec(X.data(), 1, 8);
```

As an alternative, you can use the [overloaded constructor](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Map.html#a3f621386d55a373f53082ac62579897e) which is provided for fixed size matrices only as documented by Eigen:

```
Eigen::Map<Matrix<float, 1, 8>> X_vec(X.data());
```

> Constructor in the fixed-size case.

Note that I suggest you to use this latest version, because it is less error prone and the other overloads are only for dynamic size matrices if your read the documentation very strictly:

> Constructor in the dynamic-size matrix case.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure how or if this answers my question though. The matrix I want to return is 2 x 4 while `solve` returns a 1 x 8 vector. So the dimensions of both fixed-size matrices are obviously not the same (if they were I didn't need any mapping). This is exactly my question: I want to create and return a 2 x 4 matrix that points to the same storage as the 1 x 8 vector returned by `solve`, i.e. I want to return that 1 x 8 result as 2 x 4 matrix.

Comment: Replace `8,1` by `4,2` in the examples give, by m7913d and you're done.

Comment: I think my answer is (almost) correct. You return `X`, which is `2x4` as desired. And you assign the result of `fsolve` to `X_vec`, which is `1x8`. (I changed the format from `8x1` to `1x8`)